# What do Perl's grep and map do?

Tags: perl

What does this code actually do?

```
@array = ( 'hai','hello','bar','foo' ) ;

print grep (/hai/ , @array );
print grep ("hai",@array ) ;
print map (/hai/ , @array );
print map ("hai",@array ) ;
```

Comment: I don't get it? Why would someone vote this question up?

Comment: Maybe if they had the same homework assignment?  ;)

Comment: We cover these in _Intermediate Perl_, but you can also find them in [perlfunc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc.html).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try it out...

```
print grep (/hai/ , @array );
hai
# writes all elements from @array containing 'hai' in them

print grep ("hai",@array ) ;
haihellobarfoo
# writes all elements, because "hai" evaluates to true

print map (/hai/ , @array );
1
# writes 1 for the only element from the @array, that contains 'hai'

print map ("hai",@array ) ;
haihaihaihai
# maps 'hai' to each element from @array
```

Answer (score 11):

It invokes the `map` and `grep` functions. A description of which can be found in the [perlfunc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc.html) entries for [grep](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html) and [map](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html).

Is Google broken today?

Comment: :-(  A search for "grep map hai" didn't turn up anything helpful.

Comment: It now turns up this question. ;)